# Storing file in java using arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, java-io

I am reading a file and want to save it in an array list to be able to call this method in another class for later use. 
Here's my code:

```
    package com.qmul.rfid.reader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadFile {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            ArrayList<ReadFile> fileList = new ArrayList<ReadFile> ();

            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\tagNo.txt")))
            {

                String CurrentLine;

                while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(CurrentLine);


                    fileList.add(CurrentLine);

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }
    }
```

I get an error at fileList.add(CurrentLine);. I know this is because CurrentLine does not match with ReadFile.

How can I make this work?

Thank you.

Comment: filelist is an array of readfiles, while currentline is a string. so i guess you have to create a new readfile object from a string. this obvioulsy depends on how the readfile is written in the file...

Comment: fileList should be a list of String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters in the `< ... >` brackets specify the *type* of the elements stored in the list. In this case, you want to store `String` objects. So it should be

```
ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

Comment: If you are using Java 7, then you can spare some typing and use the diamond inference, `ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<> ();`

Answer (score 1):

You could replace

ArrayList <ReadFile> fileList = new ArrayList<ReadFile> ();

by

List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

in JDK 7 style

Answer (score 0):

Try `ArrayList<String>` fileList instead of `ArrayList<ReadFile>`

Answer (score 0):

You declared an arraylist that stores `ReadFile` but you want to add a `String` to the list which causes this exception. Create another List from type `List<String>` and store the file content there.

Answer (score 0):

Type of `CurrentLine` is `String`, `fileList` should be:

```
ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrayList is of type ReadFile. So it expects you to add elements of type ReadFile. What you need is change it to String.

```
 ArrayList<ReadFile> fileList = new ArrayList<ReadFile> ();
```

to

```
 ArrayList<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArrayList` can hold objects of type `ReadFile` only, since you declared your `ArrayList` using `<ReadLine>`

```
 Change your ReadFile class to something like 

Class ReadFile {

  String line;
  ReadFile(String currentLine){
     this.line = currentLine;
  }
}
```

Then you can do

`fileList.add(new ReadFile(CurrentLine));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide String instead of readfile. because here your list is expecting readfile.

**ArrayList list = new ArrayList();**